# Display list of friends user haven't added

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display a list of friends, users isn't friends with.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users_tbl 
    INNER JOIN friends_tbl ON friends_tbl.sender_id = users_tbl.user_id 
            OR friends_tbl.receiver_id = users_tbl.user_id 
WHERE users_tbl.user_id != ? 
AND friends_tbl.list_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 16
```

users_tbl

```
user_id username
| 1    | ben
| 2    | betty
| 3    | tom
| 4    | john
```

friends_tbl

```
list_id         sender_id         receiver_id
|      1     |       1         |      2
|      2     |       1         |      3
```

In the `friends_tbl` above `Ben` is friends with `betty` and `tom`. Now `john` adds a friend let say `tom`,

friends_tbl

```
list_id         sender_id         receiver_id
|      3     |       4         |      3
```

Now the problem am having is that `john` doesn't show up on `ben` list of friends to add

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `jimmy` came from nowhere. Did you mean `john`?

Comment: Do you want "for a person - show friends of his friends who are not immediate friends for this person"? If so - does this referencing chain must finish on "friend of friend", or it may have indefinite depth?

Comment: I meant John. have edited the question.

Comment: Just show all users i havent added. currently its showing that for ben but for john it isnt

Comment: When Ben adds a user as long as that user_id his added into the friends tbl it doesnt show up for john to add.

Comment: its means to show up for John since john didnt add that user.